# jsPDF not scaling html2canvas image correctly

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I've got a function that takes a div, and saves it to a PDF document using jsPDF.
What I'm struggling with is why jsPDF isn't respecting my options

I want the PDF file to be landscape, 297mm wide (A4 landscape width) and then, then set the height of the PDF to the scaled size, and fill the PDF with the image.

My function is as below:

```
const input = document.getElementById(id);
const inputHeightMm = pxToMm(input.offsetHeight);
const inputWidthMm = pxToMm(input.offsetWidth);
const a4WidthMm = 297;
const a4HeightMm = 210;
const ratio = inputHeightMm/inputWidthMm;
console.log(a4WidthMm, a4WidthMm * ratio )

html2canvas(input)
    .then((canvas) => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const pdf = new jsPDF({
            orientation: 'landscape',
            unit: "mm",
            format: [a4WidthMm, a4WidthMm * ratio ]
        });
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, a4WidthMm, a4WidthMm* ratio );
        return pdf.save(`${v}.pdf`);
    });
```

What happens though is that I get a PDF whereby the image is cut off, as it doesn't appear to scale it to the right size.
When checking the PDF it outputs, it also says its only 4.13" x 1.96" which is 104mm wide, not the 297mm passed to it

Answer (score -1):

Can you try

```
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, undefined, undefined );
```

instead of

```
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, a4WidthMm, a4WidthMm* ratio );
```

and see if produces the same result?

the documentation points that **addImage(imageData, format, x, y, width, height, alias, compression, rotation)**, width and height is used for resizing the image generated.
If you leave it **undefined** the image will be placed on the PDF in it's original size and ratio.